# How to handle asynchronous input in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

Consider I'm building a forecasting model that uses patient data from two different tables.

The first table is `NURSE_OBSERVATIONS` and it has 3 columns:

- Fever
- Blood_Pressure
- Pulse_Rate

The second table is `LIQUID_FOLLOW` and it also has 3 columns:

- Liquids_in
- Liquids_out
- Weight

My model uses both tables as input. Therefore, my input vector's size is 6. Whenever a nurse enters values for both tables, my model is triggered and a prediction is made. However, there are couple of problems:

1. Data input is not synchronous. Nurse observations are entered 6 times a day but liquid data is entered twice a day so there is a mismatch. I want to trigger the model everytime liquid data is entered but using only last nurse observation data will lose the previous measurements.
2. Nurses are not eager on using the software to enter the data so some rows might have missing data. For example a nurse can enter Fever and Blood Pressure but skip Pulse_Rate or vice-versa.

How can we build a model for this kind of asynchronous data input? If we build a model with static input vector, say, Deep Neural Network, then missing data will give us a dimension mismatch error. Can we use seq2seq model?

I can add more information if needed.

Ps: Please remember, missing data might vary (it can be fever in one row and blood pressure in the other)